# How to set setting for one mode only?

Tags: buffers, hooks

I currently have the hook below for displaying tabs when in text mode:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda () (standard-display-ascii ?\t "!---")))
```

I only want that setting to apply in text mode.

The problem: Once I open a text file, the above setting will be set for all subsequent buffers that I open. That is not the desired outcome. How can I apply a setting to only one mode?

Comment: If you want to add some color to the glyphs using the `buffer-display-table`, here is a link to an example that plays with smiley faces, em-dash and en-dash.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9627/2287

Answer (score 1):

Use `buffer-display-table` instead of `standard-display-table`:

```el
(defun my-text-mode-hook-fun ()
   (unless buffer-display-table
      (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table)))
   (aset buffer-display-table ?\t (vconcat "!---")))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'my-text-mode-hook-fun)
```

Also note that there is the [highly configurable `whitespace-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) for your special purpose of displaying tab-characters.