# Display one character in an alternative font family

Tags: fonts

I want to change the appearance of my lozenge character.

I have tried running the following:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" ?◊ (font-spec :family "PragmataPro"))
```

However, if I type `◊` and ask Emacs to `describe-char`, I get the following:

```
             position: 38 of 74 (50%), column: 37
            character: ◊ (displayed as ◊) (codepoint 9674, #o22712, #x25ca)
              charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x25CA
               script: symbol
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 25ca" or "C-x 8 RET LOZENGE"
          buffer code: #xE2 #x97 #x8A
            file code: #xE2 #x97 #x8A (encoded by coding system utf-8)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xft:-CYEL-Iosevka-normal-normal-normal-*-18-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x9A5)

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: LOZENGE
  general-category: So (Symbol, Other)
  decomposition: (9674) ('◊')

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

As you can see, `◊` is still being rendered with Iosevka.

I have checked that PragmataPro works globally and that it makes the lozenge character appear different. Note also that the codepoint matches. To check that I'm using the `?◊` argument correctly I've also tried `'(#x25ca . #x25ca)`.

If I ask `describe-fontset` for `fontset-default` I get this:

```
…
◊ (#x25CA)
-*-PragmataPro-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
…
```

So the fontspec itself appears to have been changed. Likewise for `-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-default`.

How do I get the altered symbol to render?

Comment: In general, any character can visually be replaced with one or more different characters using the `buffer-display-table` and those replacement characters can even be colorized (if so desired).  Is that something that could suit your needs?  Here is a link to an example:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9627/2287  I have never played with a different font family though, so it may be necessary to experiment with that idea to know for sure ....