# Is it possible to use whitespace-mode without specyfing a background (or foreground) color?

Tags: faces, whitespace-mode

I like having non-breaking spaces and a few other characters represented in my buffer as visible characters. The problem I have is that whitespace-mode seems determined to set the background color. In modes where the background color is different (for example, in src blocks in Org), the ordinary space characters are really obtrusive.

I can workaround this by not having those blocks appear in a different background color, but that seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

I've tried a few things that I've found by searching, but none appear to work.

Comment: Here is a link to an example where I take a few characters such as an en-dash and an em-dash and assign a different arbitrary face to the substituted characters:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9627/2287  It is not necessary to substitute with different characters.  You can take a non-breaking space and assign a face with only a foreground specified.  I did not write up an answer to your question because you want a `whitespace-mode` specific answer, and more would be required such as a recipe to reproduce what it is you are seeing so that a `whitespace-mode` only answer can be written.

Comment: FYI:   `nobreak-space` is an Emacs *face* that can be customized; e.g., `M-x customize-face`. You can remove or change the background color if so desired ...  Here is how one might programmatically set a face with a foreground color of blue and no background color:  `(face-spec-set 'nobreak-space '((t :foreground "blue")))`.  There other functions that are more popularly used to set faces; e.g., `set-face-attribute`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually concluded that this was interaction between whitespace-mode attempting to use faces and Org mode attempting to use faces and the result just being incompatible. I told whitespace-mode to stop using faces and the result...better.